# Objects in Commutative Diagram DCpic

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I have the diagram of the following form:

```
\begindc
\obj(1,1){$A$}
\obj(3,1){$B$}
\obj(3,3){$C$}
\mor(1,1)(3,1) {$f$ }[\atright,\solidarrow]
\mor(1,1)(3,3) {$g$ }
\mor(3,1)(3,3) {$h$ }[\atright,\solidarrow]
\enddc
```

I wonder if the "objects" A,B,C must be in normal math font only, i.e. we can't replace such `A` with `\mathsf{A}` or `\mathfrak{A}` or `\mathbf{A}`. If this is really a restriction, is there any other package that allows special math fonts as "objects"?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. As well, I took the liberty to format your post a little. See [this link for more details on available formatting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: You can use `\obj(1,1)[A]{$\mathsf{A}$}`, but I strongly advise you to use a more modern and powerful package such as `tikz-cd` or `xy`.

Comment: @egreg It seems that your comment answers the question, or at least comes close to doing so.  Please consider adding it as an answer.

Comment: This got fixed now. Please see my edited answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
\obj(1,1)[A]{$\mathsf{A}$}
```

so that the optional argument sets the node name. However, there are more modern and powerful packages than `dcpic` for any sort of commutative diagram. I've used XY-pic (`\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xypic}`), but the more recent `tikz-cd` seems very promising and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by egreg, a more modern package would much easier for such things. The currently best package to learn should be `tikz-cd` (my recommendation). Here is your diagram using this.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
                                                                       & C \\
    A\mathsf{A}\mathfrak{A}\mathbf{A} \arrow{r}[swap]{f} \arrow{ur}{g} & B \arrow{u}[swap]{h}   
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In the new version (5.1) of DCpic, this got fixed. You can now write:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pictexwd,dcpic}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begindc{\commdiag}[500]
\obj(1,1){$A\mathsf{A}\mathfrak{A}\mathbf{A}$}
\obj(3,1){$A\mathsf{B}\mathfrak{B}\mathbf{B}$}
\obj(3,3){$A\mathsf{C}\mathfrak{C}\mathbf{C}$}
\mor(1,1)(3,1)[200,200]{$f$ }[\atright,\solidarrow]
\mor(1,1)(3,3) {$g$ }
\mor(3,1)(3,3) {$h$ }[\atright,\solidarrow]
\enddc
\end{document}
```

Until it gets uploaded to CTAN, you may need to add this patch to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
    \@namedef{!coloca}#1#2{\protected@edef\pilha{#1.#2}}
\makeatother
```

as [proposed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251687) by egreg.

[image]