# Problem with Commutative Diagram

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I have the following code:

```
\begindc{\commdiag}[500]
\obj(0,0){$k(s)$} 
\obj(0,2){$K$}
\obj(-1,1){$k(x)$}
\obj(1,1){$k(y)$}
\mor(0,0)(-1,1){}[+1,6]
\mor(0,0)(1,1){}[-1,6]
\mor(-1,1)(0,2){}[+1,6]
\mor(1,1)(0,2){}[+1,6]
\enddc
```

I want to put `\spec` inside every **obj**ect.

I already defined `\spec` in beginning of my document as,

```
\DeclareMathOperator\spec{spec}
```

But I get error when I do it inside the commutative diagram.

Comment: Is your question answered by one of the posts? If not, please edit your question. If yes, please accept one answer here by clicking the check mark to its left and I will delete my comment here. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

May I recommend to use the more modern package [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd)? This would look like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator\spec{spec}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={hook}]
& \spec K & \\
\spec K(x)\arrow{ur} & & \spec K(y)\arrow{ul} \\
& \spec k(s)\arrow{ur}\arrow{ul} &
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to stick to `dcpic`, you may use the starred version of `\DeclareMathOperator` as a workaround.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pictexwd,dcpic}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*\spec{spec} % Asterisk added

\begin{document}
\begindc{\commdiag}[500]
\obj(0,0){$\spec k(s)$} 
\obj(0,2){$\spec K$}
\obj(-1,1){$\spec k(x)$}
\obj(1,1){$\spec k(y)$}
\mor(0,0)(-1,1){}[+1,6]
\mor(0,0)(1,1){}[-1,6]
\mor(-1,1)(0,2){}[+1,6]
\mor(1,1)(0,2){}[+1,6]
\enddc
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Neither the normal form nor the starred form initiate display math. The error is much subtler and using the star form is not the solution.

Comment: @egreg thanks, I remove that paragraph and hope for an answer from you.

Comment: Investigating; it surely has to do with the fact that `\nolimits@` looks ahead in order to kill a `\limits` token.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in `dcpic`, which uses `\edef` instead of `\protected@edef`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dcpic,pictexwd}
\DeclareMathOperator\spec{spec}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{!coloca}#1#2{\protected@edef\pilha{#1.#2}} % had \edef
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begindc{\commdiag}[500]
\obj(0,0){$\spec k(s)$}
\obj(0,2){$\spec K$}
\obj(-1,1){$\spec k(x)$}
\obj(1,1){$\spec k(y)$}
\mor(0,0)(-1,1){}[+1,6]
\mor(0,0)(1,1){}[-1,6]
\mor(-1,1)(0,2){}[+1,6]
\mor(1,1)(0,2){}[+1,6]
\enddc
\end{document}
```

[image]